# Using React in Ionic Can it access the local file?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm using react to dev the ionic app but how can I access the local storage? Is it only angular can access the local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic offers you several options over Ionic Native for device storage that you can use with React:

- [Native Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage)
- [Secure Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage)
- [SQLite](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite)

For using Ionic Native plugins with React check Ionic [guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community#react). If you are using Capacitor it has a pretty good [API](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/storage) for device storage as well. Also if you app is very simple you can always use the browser `localStorage`.

Comment: But Native Storage, Secure Storage, and SQLite only provide for angular also.

Comment: @BryantTang they can be used with React too. I updated my answer with the link to Ionic docs where you can read how to use them with React. Hope it helps.